# How to apply a list of attributes to an object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a list of attributes for an object. I will like to loop over the list and apply them to that object.

Here is what I did:

```
attrs = ['ClearNoon',
         'ClearSunset',
         'CloudyNoon',
         'CloudySunset',
         'HardRainNoon',
         'HardRainSunset',
         'MidRainSunset',
         'MidRainyNoon',
         'SoftRainNoon',
         'SoftRainSunset',
         'WetCloudyNoon',
         'WetCloudySunset',
         'WetNoon',
         'WetSunset']

for attr in attrs:
    world.set_weather(carla.WeatherParameters.attr)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Any better suggestions please?

Comment: What do you want to set the value of the attribute? Do you wanna make new attributes or is it already there

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getattr`:

```
world.set_weather(getattr(carla.WeatherParameters, attr))
```